# Issues installing Dwarf-Fortress libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 => not found

Tags: games

When I run ./df I get this error:

```
./libs/Dwarf_Fortress: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to install that lib by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
```

But it is already installed:

```
libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version
```

I then searched around and ran this:

```
$ ldd ~/df_linux/libs/Dwarf_Fortress
```

And got a ton of libraries and I think I found the problem, it is given out by this line:

```
libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

I can't find any more information, I'm lost. How should I proceed?

Comment: Locate a file with a name starting with `libSDL_ttf_2.0.so`. In the directory, create a symbolic link called `libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0` to that file.

Comment: I ran this command:  sudo find / -type f -name "libSDL_ttf_2.0.so*", to try and find it but it didn't succeed.

Comment: I notice Dwarf Fortress expects a file called libSDL_xxx while the package is called libsdl_xxx  (lowercase). Try to find a file in lowercase and create an uppercase link to it?

Comment: Ok I found several by using lowercase and - instead of underscore. I don't which one to choose, or how to actually make a sym link. You said "in the directory", which one were you referring to?

Comment: You would create a link in the directory where you find the `lib` file, using `sudo ln -s [target file] libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0`. I don't suppose there is any harm in trying them all one by one.

Comment: But how will the sym link be connect to dwarf fortress like that? For example I have this path /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libsdl-ttf2.0-0, I run "sudo ln -s /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libsdl-ttf2.0-0    libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0"? When I run the game it will search for the sym link and find that?

Comment: Yes, it is apparently looking for a file called `libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0`. No such file exists at this moment. When you create a link with that name, linked to a file that does exist,  DF will use that.

Comment: didn't work :/ still get the same error

Comment: How can I verify if the sym link was created correctly? Does it create a file?

Comment: yeah it created a file, aff, still no luck

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you trying to run the most current version of Dwarf Fortress (0.43.05)? I was having the same problem as you. I created a soft link to libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 and it didn't work, because it was looking for a 64 bit file.

Try installing the 64 bit version instead:

`sudo apt-get install libSDL-ttf2.0-0`

You should see the file appear in your x86_64-linux-gnu directory. The game ran for me after I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

For me running this worked

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0`

Got the command from this [thread](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/issues/30931)